# Directly linking a library inside fortran code without compiler flag

Tags: fortran, gfortran

To link a library, say, BLAS, in gfortran one needs to use gfortran file.f90 -lblas to compile.

Is there any way to avoid that part by directly writing some command inside the main program so that one does not need to add some extra command while compiling?

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: Whatever answer you get (if you get one), it's worth considering that for projects of any real complexity one would expect not to be typing `gfortran .... lots_of_options` instead of, say, `make`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Theoretically, I suppose you could do some crazy stuff where you go a grab that file in code essentially linking it yourself but that would be.. unusual. The general solution to this is to use a makefile or if you are really just messing around a temporary alias in your terminal can keep things simple.